# Using should.js how to check whether a string is not present in an array?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, should.js

Like to check whether a string is present in an array we do `someArray.should.contain('str')`, but I can't find the negation case check for this.

Comment: Trott's answer appears to be correct. While I'm not very familiar with `should.js`, according to the [documentation](https://github.com/tj/should.js#not), it seems `.not` can be used anywhere, so far as I can tell.

Comment: yes it "should" be correct, but don't know why cant get it to work, giving `TypeError: undefined is not a function` at `should.not.`

Comment: someArray.should.contain('str') -> true if 'str' present in someArray. Otherwise false. right?

Comment: yes @Seram that is the case

Comment: Then why do you need another function? I'm just curious.

Comment: no actually the thing is I need to check the presence of a certain string in an array in one check, and the absence of the same string in the next check. thus I need the not condition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`.not`](https://github.com/tj/should.js#not) should work: `someArray.should.not.contain('str')`

The [`should.js` README](https://github.com/tj/should.js) does not mention `.contain()`. So if simply inserting `.not` does not work, use [`.containEql()`](https://shouldjs.github.io/#assertion-containeql).

Comment: `should.js` docs don't mention `contain`. Maybe there's some mixing and matching going on with mocha and what you really want is `containEql` or something like that?